# How to unspecify a port number while not running flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to stop Flutter web with a Headless-Server target, I managed to specify to localhost:8080 ?

Whenever I try to run any other non  flutter aplication using port 8080 in localhost I end up with

> http://localhost:8080/flutter_service_worker.js

How I created  the Headless-Server target

> flutter run -d headless-server --web-port=8080

Comment: Have you tried just killing the process?  That should release :8080.

Comment: yes restarted my laptop, still appends the /flutter_service_worker.js